# Project Euler $420$

Tags: matrices, project-euler

So the question is:

> We define $F(N)$ as the number of the $2\times 2$ positive integer matrices which have a trace less than $N$ and which can be expressed as a square of a positive integer matrix in two different ways.
>   We can verify that $F(50) = 7$ and $F(1000) = 1019$.
>
> Find $F(107)$.

And the site gives the example 
$$\begin{pmatrix}40 & 12 \\ 48 & 40\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 12 & 2\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}6 & 1 \\ 4 & 6\end{pmatrix}^2$$

After some quick googling around I found a page showing a general formula for finding the square root of a 2x2 matrix. After using the formula and the fact that all the numbers are positive integers, I came up with some simple restrictions that would help sort out which matrices have two positive square root matrices. 
With the information I wrote a function in python $H(N)$ to find the number of 2x2 matrices with a trace  $N$ that have two positive square root matrices. I then defined the function asked for in the question as $$F(N) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}H(i)$$

But when I compute F(50) I get 8, when the problem description says it is only 7! I printed out the matrices I computed, they are $$\begin{pmatrix}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}^2$$ 
$$\begin{pmatrix}10&6\\6&10\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}^2$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}13&12\\12&13\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\2&3\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}^2$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}17&8\\8&17\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&1\\1&4\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&4\\4&1\end{pmatrix}^2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}12&8\\24&28\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3&1\\3&5\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\6&4\end{pmatrix}^2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}20&8\\32&20\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&1\\4&4\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\8&2\end{pmatrix}^2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}20&16\\16&20\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&4\\4&2\end{pmatrix}^2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}18&9\\18&27\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&1\\2&5\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&3\\6&3\end{pmatrix}^2$$

Are the square roots of those first few matrices really considered different? I get the feeling those matrices with swapped rows aren't actually 'different'. Wouldn't any 2x2 square root matrix square to the same thing if the rows are swapped? If those repeat matrices aren't really different, that means I actually only found 3 matrices, and not the 7 I was supposed to find!

Comment: The [Project Euler forum](http://forum.projecteuler.net/) has a section dedicated to answering questions about understanding problems. No need to bring it up here; your question may contain some parts spoiling the fun for future solvers.

Comment: I had contact with Project Euler moderators, they really really really really do not want their questions on other sites. They want user to investigate on their own, often by computer experiments, and learn by doing.

Comment: I think the question would be fine with most of the Wikipedia stuff edited out.  Someone has listed most of these matrices in Project Euler's 420 forum anyway.

Comment: @Mike Should I remove the link and the equations stuff?

Comment: I'm sure it would definitely be much appreciated.  Why didn't you try asking on the Project Euler forum instead?

Comment: I hadn't realized there was one :p

Comment: http://forum.projecteuler.net/index.php.  There's one titled "Clarifications on Project Euler Problems".  Might want to read the stickied hk posts and mind the floating red text before posting.

Comment: Two of your matrices have an entry of $0,$ but the question asks for *positive* integer matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found your answer by the way.  One of these matrices does not fit the criteria.

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&3\\6&3\end{pmatrix}$$ does not fit the problem's definition of a positive integer matrix as $0$ is not positive.

Comment: But there's also another one with a $0$ entry.

Comment: $F(50)$ really is 7: you can't ignore the other matrix with a zero coefficient. And this discussion really should be on the Project Euler forum.

Comment: @Berci Hmm...  Good catch.  There's still something missing then...

Comment: @Berci I missed another matrix with a $0$ entry.  On closer inspection, the Project Euler forum reveals one matrix not on this list.

Comment: I actually fixed my function, now I am just making it faster! Thanks for the help! :)